# Data can't be inserted in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I got a question to ask here. Why can't my data be inserted into my database? I've already create a table in SQL Server. Here is my line of code for your reference.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into CarTab(Brand,Model,Plate,Color,Service) Values (@brand,@model,@plate,@color,@year,@service)",conn);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand", Label1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", Label2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plate", Label3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color", Label4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", Label5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@service", Label6.Text);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Pls help me. Im stuck over here. Thank you.

Comment: Please always show error message if any.

Comment: number of columns and parameters are different

Comment: Put a `try { ... } catch(Exception e) { .. }` around your `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and see if you get any exceptions when inserting. Also: please show us your connection string to your database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are missing `Year` in your command statement:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
"Insert into CarTab(Brand,Model,Plate,Color,Year,Service) 
    Values (@brand,@model,@plate,@color,@year,@service)",
conn);
```

You are supplying 6 parameters but only 5 columns.

Are you getting an error message? Usually, there will be an error message with some information; it usually looks something like this:

> There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified
>   in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must
>   match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

**EDIT.**

If you are still having problems, the next thing to do is to look at the actual error message. Let's refactor your code slightly:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString))
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into CarTab(Brand,Model,Plate,Color,Service) Values (@brand,@model,@plate,@color,@year,@service)",conn))
    {

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand", Label1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", Label2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plate", Label3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color", Label4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", Label5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@service", Label6.Text);

        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            string errorMessage = e.Message;
            //Set a label on the client to see the error message, or pause in the debugger and examine the property here.
            //throw;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are seeing no error at all, and that's what puzzled me initially, then it might actually be because your event handler isn't wired up; sometimes, the designer will unwire event handlers meaning your click and the actually code become disassociated and never run.

Check you have:

```
Button2.Click += Button2_Click;
```

In `InitializeComponent` or in the constructor or Load events.

Comment: Thank you for noticed it. I've corrected it but still, cant be inserted :(

Comment: No error. Thats why i cant figure out myself why my data not inserted in the tab.

Comment: Check your connection string; is it connecting to where you think it is?

Comment: @Stuck; in addition, are you sure this method is being called? Is Button2_Click actually wired up? Sometimes I've had the designer "unwire" events making it look like nothing was happening when clicking on a button.

Comment: Okay, after did some changes, yeayyyy! Finally! Thank you @dash. U make my day :)

Comment: @Stuck You're welcome! In addition, the `Using` statement is very useful when dealing with none framework resources (like database connections, and streams) so I would advise you to try and use it more often. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx for the summary :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is missing the year column in it:

```
INSERT INTO CarTab(Brand, Model, Plate, Color, Year, Service)
```